# Can I merge a non-versioned site into a trunk?

Tags: svn, merge

I have a project in svn, and there a version of the site online. But some changes are made directly with FTP (it's bad, I know).

So, I need to get the project online, and merging it with my trunk.

How can I do that ? : just 1-download the project, 2-create a branch, and 3-merge the branch with the trunk?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what revision or tag the online site was originally deployed from, then yes your method would work. I recommend creating your branch from the revision or tag which the online files were originally pulled from.

The other option would be to `svn update -r` to the revision the online files were derived from, then just copy them over into your working copy, `svn update`, and `svn commit`. But if the changes are complex the branch method may work better.